# Worm in water identification help

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I live in Auckland New Zealand. I have been growing Chia seeds in bowls with just water. I noticed after a couple of weeks, these white / transparent worms appeared in the bowl. It seemed that they came out of nowhere? I have seen them crawling in my bathroom before. And the really big ones can get up to a 2-3 cm, so they can't possibly be drain fly larvae as they can grow to a few cm? I also did not see any drain flies nearby. I wonder what type of worm are they? I hope they don't come from tape water, because I have been drinking from it directly.

[image]

[image]

[EDIT] - Photo of the worm in bigger size (~1.5cm):
[image]

Comment: Are you sure they're worms? They look like sprouts, either roots or stems.

Comment: They look like mosquito larvae, but it is quite hard to be sure: They are so tiny.

Comment: Agree with @Astrolamb they are sprout of green grams

Comment: @Astrolamb They are moving around!

Comment: @bli They are tiny now - but they are growing. I have seen 3cm big ones.

Comment: @Astrolamb Yes there are stems and roots in the photo. The other smaller ones are the worms. They are moving and crawling in the water. They can crawl out of water as well. Amphibious?

Comment: @JerryH Try to add photos of the larger ones.

Comment: @bli - 1.5cm one

Comment: In the end, I don't think this looks like a mosquito larva.

Comment: They won't be from the tap water, unless you have had something lay eggs in the tap nozzle itself; NZ has high standards of water quality for municipal water and tap water is safe to drink throughout NZ.